# xsl value-of select returns empty when using a parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get data out of some xml files using xsltproc and a stringparam but I cannot get it to work. This is a bit verbose but I've given some examples of what I have tried.

Say I have 2 XML files x.xml and y.xml where the only schema difference between them is the root tag.
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<x>
  <C>ABC</C>
  <D>DEF</D>
</x>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<y>
  <C>XYZ</C>
  <D>UVW</D>
</y>
```

And now I write 2 xsl files z1.xsl and z2.xsl to process the XML
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="x/C" />
    <xsl:text>),(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="x/D"/>
    <xsl:text>)&#x0a;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only difference between z1.xsl and z2.xsl is the "x/C" is replaced with "y/C" and "x/D" is replaced with "y/D" in the select's.

Now I run:

$ xsltproc z1.xsl x.xml

(ABC),(DEF)

and

$ xsltproc z2.xsl y.xml

(XYZ),(UVW)

which is what I want. So far, so good.

Now I modify the xsl file, lets call it z3.xsl to add a parameter
I add

```
<xsl:param name="xOrY"/>
```

and modify the select lines line this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($xOrY,'/C')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($xOrY,'/D')"/>
```

Now when I run

$ xsltproc --stringparam xOrY x z3.xsl x.xml

(x/C),(x/D)

which is of course not what I wanted. I did some searching and found that my selects should look like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[name()=concat($xOrY,'/C')]" />
<xsl:value-of select="*[name()=concat($xOrY,'/D')]" />
```

but that produces this output

(),()

I have also tried using local-name() instead of name() and tried adding a '/' in front of the '*' in the select but still get the same results.

Comment: Maybe try `<xsl:value-of select="*[name()=$xOrY]/C" />`

Comment: Well SOB. It's that simple. Thanks Daniel. Any idea why the concat didn't work?

Comment: The result of your concat would be the string `x/C` so the comparison in the predicate (inside the square brackets) would be `name()='x/C'` which is false. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[name()=$xOrY]/C" />
```

Your concat didn't work because the result of the concat would be the string `x/C` so the comparison in the predicate (inside the square brackets) would be `name()='x/C'` which is false.